# jQuery Mobile Alert/Confirmation dialogs

Tags: dialog, jquery-mobile

Is there a nice Sencha-like jQuery Mobile solution for Alerts and Confirmation dialogs?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This plugin for jQM will style the confirmation box with jQM styling

http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/

**EDIT :** This plugin has now been supserseeded by SimpleDialog2 which can be found here:

http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos2/

Comment: This plugin is indeed awesome. The popup dialog is what I was looking for. It is worth a look if you don't know it.

Comment: If you happen to use Backbone, here is my simple implementation http://derekzeng.me/blog/2013/12/11/diy-jqm-popup-dialog/

Answer (score 41):

Yes, the plugin is nice. However, if you don't need the full functionality, it's still much lighter in weight to roll your own simple dialogs. I use this:

```
<div data-role="dialog" id="sure" data-title="Are you sure?">
  <div data-role="content">
    <h3 class="sure-1">???</h3>
    <p class="sure-2">???</p>
    <a href="#" class="sure-do" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-rel="back">Yes</a>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="c" data-rel="back">No</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this:

```
function areYouSure(text1, text2, button, callback) {
  $("#sure .sure-1").text(text1);
  $("#sure .sure-2").text(text2);
  $("#sure .sure-do").text(button).on("click.sure", function() {
    callback();
    $(this).off("click.sure");
  });
  $.mobile.changePage("#sure");
}
```

You can use these wherever you need the confirmation dialog:

```
areYouSure("Are you sure?", "---description---", "Exit", function() {
  // user has confirmed, do stuff
});
```

Comment: this code appears to work, however try setting a dialog, cancelling, setting cancelling, then confirming.  it will confirm twice.  basically continues to fire the event.  why?

Comment: this is also not blocking.
if you do `areYouSure(<params here>);alert("blabla");` it will show the dialog AND the alert, unlike a plain javascript alert/prompt. This is true for any instruction after the function call, not just alert...

Comment: Great way, I like the callback style!

Comment: a better version would be to do one without markup, i.e. document.append the html of the divs, I have one for a modal dialog. but not a yes/no dialog.

Comment: Nice code Peter. Exactly what I needed. Thanks for sharing.

@aherrick, without the 'off' call inside the function the 'on' call will keep adding function handlers. JQM adds a new function call each time you call 'on', so that's why you call 'off' to remove it when done. I guess maybe Peter added the 'off' call after your post, or else you had remove the 'off' yourself, which created the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Excellent code @ Peter, but not to be generating consecutive events, it might be better to use unbind (), like this:

```
function areYouSure(text1, text2, button, callback) {
  $("#sure .sure-1").text(text1);
  $("#sure .sure-2").text(text2);
  $("#sure .sure-do").text(button).unbind("click.sure").on("click.sure", function() {
    callback(false);
    $(this).off("click.sure");
  });
  $.mobile.changePage("#sure");
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I had similar problem. I wanted to have easy to use function like standard `confirm()`.

Since dialogs are deprecated in jquery mobile 1.4 [(documentation)](http://api.jquerymobile.com/dialog/), I decided to create my own fiddle:

```
function confirmDialog(text, callback) {
var popupDialogId = 'popupDialog';
$('<div data-role="popup" id="' + popupDialogId + '" data-confirmed="no" data-transition="pop" data-overlay-theme="b" data-theme="b" data-dismissible="false" style="max-width:500px;"> \
                    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">\
                        <h1>Question</h1>\
                    </div>\
                    <div role="main" class="ui-content">\
                        <h3 class="ui-title">' + text + '</h3>\
                        <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b optionConfirm" data-rel="back">Yes</a>\
                        <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b optionCancel" data-rel="back" data-transition="flow">No</a>\
                    </div>\
                </div>')
    .appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer);
var popupDialogObj = $('#' + popupDialogId);
popupDialogObj.trigger('create');
popupDialogObj.popup({
    afterclose: function (event, ui) {
        popupDialogObj.find(".optionConfirm").first().off('click');
        var isConfirmed = popupDialogObj.attr('data-confirmed') === 'yes' ? true : false;
        $(event.target).remove();
        if (isConfirmed && callback) {
            callback();
        }
    }
});
popupDialogObj.popup('open');
popupDialogObj.find(".optionConfirm").first().on('click', function () {
    popupDialogObj.attr('data-confirmed', 'yes');
});
```

}

I noticed strange behavior, when redirecting/clearing window was done on "Yes" button click. It started working in afterClose event, so that's why it's a bit complicated.

[Here is a jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EELLj/2/)

Comment: close enough to what i was looking for. i ended up just leaving the defined modal on the page, removed the first few lines along with the $(event.target).remove(); Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This plugin
[craftpip/jquery-confirm](http://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm)

was designed for mobile initially, is based on the bootstrap3 framework.
Supports alerts, confirms, modals, dialogs, and many options.

Simple to use.

```
$.alert({
    title: 'title here',
    content: 'content here',
    confirm: function(){
        //on confirm
    },
    cancel: function(){
        // on cancel
    }
})
```

Supports ajax loading, CSS3 animations, Responsive, etc.

[EDIT]
Detailed documentation can be found [here](http://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm)

Features list:

- Themes (android themes included)
- Ajax loading content.
- CSS3 animations (2D & 3D animations)
- Animation Bounce options
- Auto close (triggers a action after timeout)
- Icons
- background dismiss (closes the modal on clicking outside the modal)
- Keyboard actions (ENTER/SPACE triggers confirm, ESC triggers cancel)
- Detailed API for programmically changing content in modal.

I'm actively developing the plugin, please do suggest improvements and features.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen anything with alerts as I think it uses the native look and feel for them. You should be able to customize them through another jQuery plugin and/or CSS.

Here is a [jQuery Example](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/projects/js/jquery/alerts/demo/)

UPDATE:

Well the link is a 404 now and jQM 1.2 is out and offers popups:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/index.html

Comment: you link has gone into a 404 link

Comment: here's the good link: http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/12/jquery-alert-dialogs/

Answer (score -2):

Try,

```
if (confirm("Are you sure?"))
{
   /*code to execute when 'Ok' bttn selected*/
}
```

Comment: It works but uses the default Javascript dialog. The design is minimal and on Android it shows the URL of the page that called the confirm() function. This would be confusing for users.