# alert message not showed in jquery mobile application

Tags: android, jquery

the alert message is not showed in android emulator.
I've already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15091674/3649862) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19907581/3649862), and did not find any info that helped.

The code is:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "-url here-",
    data: { - data here - },
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "xml",
    statusCode: {
       0: function () {
            alert('Thank You');
       },
       200: function () {
            alert('Thank You');
       }
    }
});
```

and:

```
if (hourFrom1=="N/A" || minFrom1=="N/A" || hourTo1=="N/A" || minTo1=="N/A") {
    alert('Please check time input.');
    return;
}
if (customer=="" || project=="" || assignment=="") {
    alert('Please check customer/activity description input.');
    return;
}
```

I use jquery-1.11.1.min.js.

None of those 4 alerts doesn't work. In the first part, the data is sent OK.

They work pretty well in browsers though..

What am I missing?

Thank you.

### EDIT

JS is allowed:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
WebSettings s = myWebView.getSettings();
s.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. It come from [HERE](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=752).

I had to add to MainActivity.java file the following line (the second one):

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

That did the trick.

I also found the answer in [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12576142/3649862) post.

Answer (score 0):

try include: http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js in a script tag.

Comment: I tried and included `jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js`. It didn't help. Or is that version not OK?

Comment: Hmm ok was just making a best guess anyways, I found something else for you to try. Someone else has had somewhat the same problem at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747382/jquery-mobile-alert-confirmation-dialogs